# How to create Dict from a Python list

Tags: python

I have a list of random objects generated from a Model (querySet).
I intend to create a separate list of objects using some but not all of the values of the objects from the original list.

For instance,

```py
people = [
    {'name': 'John', 'age': 20, 'location': 'Lagos'},
    {'name': 'Kate', 'age': 40, 'location': 'Athens'},
    {'name': 'Mike', 'age': 30, 'location': 'Delhi'},
    {'name': 'Ben', 'age': 48, 'location': 'New York'}
]
```

Here's what I've tried:

```py
my_own_list = []
my_obj = {}

for person in people:
    my_obj['your_name'] = person['name']
    my_obj['your_location'] = person['location']
    my_own_list.append(my_obj)
```

However, my code created only one obj, repeatedly four times.

Comment: That there is already a dict, or to say a list of dicts. you can't have a dict with repeating keys, so you'll ned a list to keep all the dicts in

Comment: first thing to do is learning how to debug with print

Comment: Moving the obj variable initialization within the loop solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new object for every new person:

```
my_own_list = []

for person in people:
    my_obj = {}
    my_obj['your_name'] = person['name']
    my_obj['your_location'] = person['location']
    my_own_list.append(my_obj)
```

Comment: change the my_dict into `my_obj = {'your_name': person['name'], 'your_location': person['location']}`

Comment: or do it all in one line :D `my_own_list = list([{'your_name': person['name'], 'your_location': person['location']} for person in people])`

Answer (score 1):

### Your code corrected

```
my_own_list = []

for person in people:
    # every time you create a new dictionary
    my_obj = {}
    my_obj['your_name'] = person['name']
    my_obj['your_location'] = person['location']
    my_own_list.append(my_obj)
```

### One-liner that uses list and dict comprehension :-)

```
[{k:v for k,v in p.items() if k in ['name', 'location']} for p in people]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getting the same entry because you predefine the dict you put into a list and overwrite the same dict - so each dict in your list references to the same dict in memory and hence they're all the same

you could use a list comprehension like so :

```
my_own_list = [{"a": person["name"], "b": person["location"]} for person in people]
```

Answer (score 0):

please declare my_obj inside the for loop . it will work .